# Some problems about acumos platform

Tags: acumos

Thanks again for Bryan's guidance. With AIO3.0.1, Acumos platform under k8s has been successfully installed and the platform website can be accessed successfully, All pods are running.

A few days after I used the platform, I had several problems：

**1.Acumos is a platform which enhances the development, training and deployment of AI models. But I didn't find the location of the model development and training modules in the platform.**

2.When I go to *Home / Design Studio / ML Workbench / Projects*, it is always in the loading state. Multiple Logout-SIGN IN, I can enter the project interface, but what I see is that the projects can only be associated with notebooks, and I don't see other functions. Is this normal?

**3.Can the Acumos platform upload my own algorithms and datasets to train the model like Microsoft azure?**

4.I haven't found a document about how to use the platform, can I have one?
(Only have *Acumos Documentation Release 1.0*)

Answer (score 0):

The forever-loading behavior in the design studio sounds like a bug.

To answer your question #4 about documentation, please see https://docs.acumos.org/en/boreas/

Answer (score 0):

For your query : 2.When I go to Home / Design Studio / ML Workbench / Projects, it is always in the loading state. Multiple Logout-SIGN IN, I can enter the project interface, but what I see is that the projects can only be associated with notebooks, and I don't see other functions. Is this normal?

We do had similar issue, but its not consistent.  Could you please check and confirm whether the Project-Catalog, Project-WebComponent and Project-Service deployment is up and running in your k8s deployment environment.

Comment: mlwb-project-779d9fff8c-8sqdz,mlwb-project-catalog-webcomponent-5598c85c87-h7mnb,mlwb-project-webcomponent-569496dd55-c9mh7,deployment is up and running in my k8s deployment environment successfully.
But here's an error message:
Server is not available.Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.104.209.167:9090